# Creating a list to produce on View without using a foreach statement in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to produce a list of Viewbag items in the controller with a foreach statement. Then use those ViewBag items in the View. Like this shows.

[image]

My issue is that I do not want to use a Foreach statement in the view. The View has images pulled from the database and are on the view in a pattern (Simular to Above). So the Foreach statement in the View will not give me what I need. The images are held in a Row/Column configuration and not all areas will have an Image. I know how to do a Foreach statement, my issue is iterating over the records and giving the ViewBag a number or name and number. Like `ViewBag.Name[i] = the item`. So the Comments below are fine for developing a repeating list of items in a table etc. I know how to do that.

I have two pieces of code from the controller and neither of them are producing a list of ViewBag items.

```
  var list = db.TCards.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
  foreach(var item in list)
  {
     ViewBag.name = item.CardName;
  }
  return View();
```

The best result would be something like this `ViewBag.name[i] = item.CardName;`
This second one is really not working although would give me the best scenario for iteration. I just do not know how to pull the image name I need for the View. `item.Cardname`

```
  var list = db.TCards.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     ViewBag.Name[i] = list[i];
  }      
  return View();
```

This may be a stretch and maybe cannot be done. thanks for your help!

UPDATE: Changed and Added some things above. What I am attempting to do is develop a list in the Controller. So that I do not have to do a Foreach or For in the View. Creating a set of `ViewBag.Name[i].CardURL` and placing that in the view as `@ViewBag.Name1.CardUrl` or something like that. The List has to be complete in the Controller first.

`@ViewBag.Name1.CardUrl`, `@ViewBag.Name2.CardUrl`, `@ViewBag.Name3.CardUrl`, `@ViewBag.Name4.CardUrl` etc.

So when I put them in the view it would look like this:

```
       <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/@ViewBag.Name1.CardURL" style="width:145px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:100px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/@ViewBag.Name2.CardURL" style="width:145px; padding-top:100px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>

        </div>
```

And then repeat in another row with a set of columns.
Maybe there is another way to do this?

Comment: well u can always create another  ViewBag for the image and then in the view, foreach literate item u can do  like (List<ImageTable>)ViewBag.ImageList.Where(x => x.TCards == @item[i].Id).First().ImagePath

Comment: It would be helpful to know which controller action you are referring to using. Or not use either and just create a viewbag for the list. Showing your example in a solution would be helpful as well.

Comment: If I not misunderstand your question, you are trying to set the list to ViewBag. You can work with LINQ without the `foreach` loop: `ViewBag.Name = db.TCards.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).Select(x => x.Cardname).ToList();`

Comment: Using `.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())` does NOT guarantee randomness.

Comment: @ScottPurtan - Your question is terribly confusing. Can you please try to rephrase and perhaps read [ask] to help hone your question?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I added more explaination and an image above. I hope this helps clear up the question.

Comment: If you need to generate some html for each element of the list, you will need a loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign `list` into `ViewBag.Name`

```cs
  var list = db.TCards.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10).ToList();
  ViewBag.Name = list;
  return View();
```

And in your view, you can get the specific data using index as below

```
       <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/@(ViewBag.Name[0].CardURL)" style="width:145px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:100px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/@(ViewBag.Name[1].CardURL)" style="width:145px; padding-top:100px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: This is only doing what I am trying to avoid, in a different way. I will try to rephrase my Question.

Comment: I have updated how to get a specific element from the list without foreach, you may take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found to work and I am happy with the results, just not happy of how I had to do it. So if someone has a better way to achieve this, Please provide an answer.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Reading()
{
   var list = db.TCards.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2);
   ViewBag.Name = list;

   return View(list);
}
```

I changed it to Take(2) so that it would be more random. I was getting dupes sometimes.

CHTML View: Very Ugly!

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name = item.CardURL;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name2 = item.CardURL;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name3 = item.CardURL;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name4 = item.CardURL;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name5 = item.CardURL;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name6 = item.CardURL;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name7 = item.CardURL;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name8 = item.CardURL;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.name9 = item.CardURL;
    }
 <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/@ViewBag.Name1.CardURL" style="width:145px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:100px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/@ViewBag.Name2.CardURL" style="width:145px; padding-top:100px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    </div>
```

And so on through nine. I can put the viewbag.name1 - 9 anywhere I want on the page.